# AWS SNS unsubscribe endpoint from topic during deleting endpoint

Tags: amazon-sns

I need to unsubscribe endpoints from topics during the deletion.
I see that when I delete an endpoint I still have a reference(to just deleted endpoint) in topic subscriptions.
How am I supposed to remove it?
I see that SnsClient in java has this method

```
snsClient.unsubscribe("sunbscription-arn");
```

But I don't keep subscription arns in my db. Is there any way to avoid keeping these arns?

Answer (score 3):

I tried to unsubscribe endpoint from topic by following python code (use boto):

```
def _unsubscribe_from_topic(topic_arn, endpoint):

    conn = connect_to_region('your_region_name','AWS_ACCESS_KEY', 'AWS_SECRET_KEY')

    r = conn.get_all_subscriptions_by_topic(topic_arn)
    for i in r.get('ListSubscriptionsByTopicResponse')\
              .get('ListSubscriptionsByTopicResult')\
              .get('Subscriptions'):
        if i.get('Endpoint') == endpoint:
            subscription = i.get('SubscriptionArn')
            conn.unsubscribe(subscription)
            return True
    return False
```

reference: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/sns.html